# Chamisha Ushloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

135 was (in *amos* (cubits)) the width of the *azaros* (and the length of the *ezras nashim*) in the second *bes hamikdash*.

Answer (score 5):

Yaakov was 135 at the end of the period foretold in Paroah's dreams.

Answer (score 3):

Matza   =   135

Answer (score 3):

The 135th day from Rosh Hashanna is Tu Bishvat, if Heshvan and Kislev is Mele'im (have 30 days) - like in this year.

Answer (score 2):

Bar Kochva's revolt was crushed in 135 CE